# Java runtime exec getInputStream when process pauses

Tags: java

I am creating a wrapper for a executable that runs on the windows command line. The executable takes a few commands then attempts to connect to another device. then it outputs and ERROR! or Ready For "Device Name" i do not get this message until the app exits. The problem is this app is a tunnel allowing me to run telnet on the external box but i need to make sure the Device is ready this is my code.

```
public void startUDPTunnel() {
    //TODO Pull Amino serial number from webportal
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream inConfig = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
    try {
        prop.load(inConfig);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    String server = prop.getProperty("server");//config.GetProp("server");
    System.out.println(server);
    String port = prop.getProperty("port");//config.GetProp("port");
    System.out.println(port);
    String location = prop.getProperty("location");//config.GetProp("location");
    System.out.println(location);
    String url = prop.getProperty("URL");
    System.out.println(url);
    String input = "";
    try {
        input = getSerial(url);
        System.out.println(input);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(location+"udptunnel.exe -c 127.0.0.1 23 "+input+" "+server+" "+port+" 127.0.0.1 23");  

        threadSleep();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.equals("ERROR!")){
                System.out.println("There was an ERROR");
            }
            if(line.equals("Ready for \""+input+"\"")){
                System.out.println("Load Telnet");
            }
        }
        p.destroy();
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}
```

Sorry there is a lot of debug code left in this function.

EDIT

OK I am pretty sure know what the issue is bufferReader.readLine() requires a \n or \r or just hangs is there anyway to watch the stream with out the buffer?

Comment: If you want your code to pick up the Process output while it's running, that Process is going to need to output something while it's running and not just on exit.

Comment: The process does output something it outputs "ERROR!" or "Ready for " if it does become ready then it waits until you connect with a telnet via the tunnel once you exit telnet the process exits. but if it has an error then the process ends right then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), and then use [`redirectErrorStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream(boolean)).  I *think* this will cause `stdout` of the process to be unbuffered.  And even if it doesn't, you'll only have to read from one `InputStream` to get both `stdout` and `stderr`.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my problem the applications that i am executing with java do not have a EOL at the end of the line in fact they just hang on the line For example telnet waits for the username then the password. i am not sure this is proper but it works and is what i am going to use for now

```
while((i=br.read())!=-1){
    ch += (char)i;
}
```

This outputs every char as they come in when then i just make sure the string contains what i am looking for!